# How to count total number of responses received from aggregate function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an mongo query which is

```
 try {
    const reviews = await Entity.aggregate([
      { $match: { cities: ObjectId(req.params.cityId), public: true } },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'reviews',
          localField: '_id',
          foreignField: 'entityId',
          as: 'avgRating',
        },
      },
      {
        $addFields: {
          avgRating: {
            $avg: {
              $map: {
                input: '$avgRating',
                in: '$$this.rating',
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          admin: 0,
          createdAt: 0,
          updatedAt: 0,
        },
      },

    ]);
    res.send(reviews);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send();
  }
```

It works fine but in `addFields` I want to add one more field called `noOfReviews` which will have the total number of responses gotten from `$match` and `$lookup`.

I tried this

```
 totalCount: [
        { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } },
       ]
```

I put this inside `addFields` after the `avg`  but this didnt work.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$size` operator to get count of an array means cont of `avgRating` array,

- add this in `$addFields`

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      noOfReviews: {
        $size: "$avgRating"
      },
      avgRating: ... // skipping
    }
  },
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kSJD7Kg7rub)